# Read word by word from a text file in Qt4

Tags: c++, qt

I want to read a text file word by word in Qt4 (to which I am very new to be honest), I want and write in another file one word per line. I could do this in C++ without any problems, but when I tried to use the ifstream and ofstream in Qt4, i had errors. Here is my Qt4 code (in the event listener of a button)

```
// a string that holds the text inside the File Name index
   QString str = ui->txtIndex->toPlainText();

   // Check if this is a text file
   if(str.endsWith(".txt")){
       qDebug() << "a file";

       // Create a File object that points to the file we input in the File Name
       QFile mFile("/home/mohamed/Desktop/index.dat");
       QFile readFile(str);

           // Check if there is a problem
           if(!mFile.open(QFile::WriteOnly | QFile::Append )){
               qDebug() << "Could not open the file for writing";
               return;
           }




           QTextStream in(&readFile);
           if(!readFile.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text )){
               qDebug() << "Could not open the file for writing";
               return;
           }
           // a text stream object that will print in the the file
           QTextStream out(&mFile);

           QString mText = in.readAll();
            mText.replace("de","BURGER");
            ui->txtSearchResult->setText(mText);
           out << mText;

///home/mohamed/NetBeansProjects/indexing/fichier.txt


           mFile.flush();

            readFile.close();
           mFile.close();


   }

   else{
       qDebug() << " A FOLDER";
   }
```

and here is my normal C++ code that works fine !

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include <dirent.h>
using namespace std;

bool searchArray(string s, string undesired[]){
for(int i=0; i<50;i++){
    if(undesired[i] == s){
        return true;
        break;
    }
}
   return false;
 }
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
// array filled with undesired words
string undesired[50] = {"je","tu","il","nous","faut","faire","de","ce","se"};
// the directory


// the file to read from
ifstream reader("fichier");
// the file to write to
ofstream writer("index.dat", ios_base::app);
string word, message =" ";
int count = 0;


while(!reader.eof()){ // while there still is stuff to read
    reader >> word;  // read one word

    if(!searchArray(word,undesired)){ // if it's an undesired word

        writer << word <<"\t\t\t\t" <<count<<endl;// print it in the text

        cout<<"word inserted"<<endl;
     }
    count++;
      }






return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could combine [QString::split](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#split) and [QStringList::join](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qstringlist.html#join) to achieve your aim:

```
#include <QFile>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QTextStream>

int main()
{
    QFile ifile("in.txt");
    ifile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text);

    // read whole content
    QString content = ifile.readAll();
    // extract words
    QStringList list = content.split(" ");

    ifile.close();

    QFile ofile("out.txt");
    ofile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text);

    QTextStream out(&ofile);

    // join QStringList by "\n" to write each single word in an own line
    out << list.join("\n");

    ofile.close(); 

    return 0;
}
```