# How to use the >> operator in a Qt file stream while loop

Tags: c++, qt

How do you use the >> input operator in the Qt file stream's while loop? (is it possible instead of making use of fin.atEnd() ?) 
What I want to do is import word by word instead of whole lines.
Here is my code below, I have marked the line in question:

```
QTextStream cout(stdout);
QTextStream cin(stdin);

int main()
{
    //read & write a string to and from file
    //open input file
    QFile inData("input.txt");
    inData.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    QTextStream fin(&inData); //setup file stream input

    //open ouput file
    QFile outData("output.txt");
    outData.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    QTextStream fout(&outData); //setup file stream output

    QString next;

    //copy one file to another
    while (fin >> next)   ////////////////THIS LINE/////////////
    {
        next = fin.readLine();
        next += '\n';
        fout << next;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks?

This question [Read word by word from a text file in Qt4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9352708/read-word-by-word-from-a-text-file-in-qt4) solves the word by word import part, but I still would still like to know if you can use the >> input operator within Qt as shown above. (In standard c++ you can use either fin >> next OR fin.eof())

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read word by word from a text file in Qt4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9352708/read-word-by-word-from-a-text-file-in-qt4)

Comment: It is not very clear why you are reading `next` in `fin >> next` and then immediately reading it again in `next = fin.readLine();`. Do you want to print out every other word, or every line without the first word, or anything like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`operator>>` returns the stream reference:

```
QTextStream &operator>>(QTextStream &stream, QString &next);
```

and there is no implicit conversion between `QTextStream&` and `bool`. You could however use `QTextStream::Status` for this like so:

```
while((fin >> next).status() == QTextStream::Ok)
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thx the main reason is mostly to learn what is possible with Qt and to compare that with standard c++

Comment: @Rhdr Well Qt is no magic. It is standard C++ done in cross-platform way (so you do not have to figure it out yourself for each platform). It has cleaner API and when using it you can be sure it will work on all supported platforms without modification. Internally it uses standard C++ so you don't have to (because it is often a pain).

Comment: I started this semester on Qt, and to be honest it still feels a bit awkward. That and our textbook is not really written in layman's terms anymore, but we'll get there. Need to ace this before the May exam