# How to read in a file word by word in QT?

Tags: c++, qt

As you can probably tell I am new to QT and I am attempting to import my console app's src code and headers to qt to build a GUI.  I am stuck on one particular function which is supposed to load a file and read it in word by word.  I know how to do this in C++, but in QT I have been at it for hours and I am not quite sure how to go about it.  Along with reading in the file, I have to insert a string (or in this case type T) by using my own personal insert function (irrelevant to the question).

As of right now i am doing which I know is not working for conversion reasons etc:

```
template <typename T>
bool HashTable<T>::load(const char* filename)
{
    QString word;
    QFile inputFile(filename);
    QTextStream fin(filename);
  //  std::ifstream iss;
    QString line;
  //  iss.clear();
   // iss.open(filename);
    while (fin >> word)
    {
        insert(word);
    }
    fin.close();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9352708/read-word-by-word-from-a-text-file-in-qt4)

Comment: `QTextStream fin(&inputFile);`. A quick google found this [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html). Learning how to read it is a valuable skill.

Answer (score 0):

[`QTextStream`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextstream.html) does (to my knowledge) not support word-by-word reading of files, it only support reading a certain number of characters (via `read(qint64 maxlen)`), reading entire lines (via `readLine(qint64 maxlen = 0)`) or a combination of the above. An example on how to do this is described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5445381/9103250).

What you might do - in order to get a list of words - is reading line-by-line, and splitting each read line with [`QString's`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html) [split()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#split) function, using space as separator.

Answer (score 0):

```
template <typename T>
bool HashTable<T>::load(const char* filename)
{
    QFile inputFile(filename);
    if(!inputFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
        QMessageBox::information(0, "error", inputFile.errorString());
    }

    QTextStream fin(&inputFile);

    while(!fin.atEnd()) {

        QString line = in.readLine();    
        QStringList words = line.split(" ");    
        foreach(QString word, words){
           insert(word); 
        }

    }

    filename.close();
    return true;
}
```

You have to first open your file for reading. Then textstream should be read line by line. In above code I read a line and then split it to words using space (" ") as the token. Then you can read words from the QStringlist.

Comment: Essentially what I wrote, but you took the time to include the code for it :) Hope the OP actually comes back and upvotes and accepts the answer.